# Can't use microphone from headphones on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, microphone, headphones

I have a Logitech PRO headset with a microphone. But when I connect it with a single 3.5mm jack is only uses the headphones but does not recognize the microphone. I know that there are those adapters for that but for some reason I did not receive one.

I wouldn't be asking this question if I didn't try it the same way with a single 3.5mm jack on a Windows machine and it worked perfectly. It recognized the headset and the microphone.

But on Ubuntu it seems to me like it's using the laptop microphone.

Is there any fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed if it works on Windows, then it is not a hardware issue. Likely, the microphone is available as a device, but is not used by default. Check Settings - Sound. You see a drop down for Input Device. If your headphone microphone conforms to standards, it should be selectable in the dropdown menu.

In principle, once the device set, it should be remembered and automatically be selected as the default the next time it is plugged in.

An additional point of attention that may have caused your issue: prefer to plug in the headphones only when you are logged in. Then the desktop will ask whether these are headphones or headphones and microphone. Make sure to make the correct choice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I don't see any additional microphones in the settings apart from the built-in one, and when I plug the headphones only while I'm logged in it doesn't ask me for anything.